# How do I disable one of the multiple backgrounds in CSS?

Tags: css

I am setting multiple backgrounds on element and then would like to disable one of the backgrounds without repeating the other ones. Can I do that somehow?

I would like to achieve exactly the same effect as below, but **without repeating `B, C, D`** in `:hover, :focus` selectors.

```
.selector {
  background: A, B, C, D;
}


.selector:hover,
.selector:focus {
  background: none, B, C, D;
}
```

Something like that:

```
.selector {
  background: A, B, C, D;
}


.selector:hover,
.selector:focus {
  background: none,;
}
```

Comment: have you tried doing `background: B, C, D;` on hover/focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background:none` is a keyword and will override all other statements.

Unfortunately, there is no solution without repeating the declarations. you can't overide **part** of a multiple declaration.

Use `transparent` instead.

```
.selector {
  background: A, B, C, D;
}


.selector:hover,
.selector:focus {
  background: transparent, B, C, D;
}
```

or just remove the first background all together.

```
.selector:hover,
.selector:focus {
  background: B, C, D;
}
```

Advanced CSS Custom Properties (also known as CSS variables) can help here though if you define your backgrounds as "variables" you only need to change the definiton of that variable on `:hover.

```css
:root {
  --background-a: url(http://www.placebacon.net/100/100);
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: var(--background-a);
}

div:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  --background-a: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Okay, so the answer is you can't do that without repeating other background declarations. I'm using Sass, so I was already using variables, but I was wondering if you could make it even more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set the `background-size` property to `0` for the background(s) you wish to hide like so:

```
background-size: 0, auto, auto, auto;
```

Reference: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-hide-one-or-more-background-images-when-using-multiple-backgrounds-in-css

Comment: All true, but you still have to repeat size declarations (`auto` in your example) for all other backgrounds.

Comment: yep, that you have to